# Trying to play a .MP3 using the MediaPlayer class; doesn't work

Tags: c#, media-player

I have little experience at playing .MP3 files in C# applications, but I have a need to do so. I tried writing a simple, .NET Core 3 console app over the weekend. It worked fine. I thought it would be easy to duplicate what I'd done at home to my work environment, but it's not playing to .MP3 file. Here's the code that I have in a WPF app we're writing:

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private void PlayDrinkingSound()
{
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
    {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Audio\Slurping-SoundBible.com-755296861.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
    mediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

The differences between the two is at home I wrote a .NET Core 3.1 console app. At work its a .NET 4.5.2 WPF app.

I've set the Build Action on the .MP3 to Resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here maybe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer?view=netcore-3.1)

> When distributing media with your application, you cannot use a media
>   file as a project resource. In your project file, you must instead set
>   the media type to Content and set CopyToOutputDirectory to
>   PreserveNewest or Always.